# PowerShell: calculate delta between successive values of the rawvalue property for each counter

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

'evening,

I'm brand new at PowerShell scripting (and to this site) and need to write a script that:

- gathers performance counters (in this case, TCP) several times
- calculates the difference between successive values of the rawvalue property of each counter

Stipulating that every interval T the script iterates through the performance counters N times, and said performance counters are "A" and "B", and we're counting from 0, it needs to perform the following calculations:

```
A[1st] - A[0th], 
A[2nd] - A[1st], 
A[3rd] - A[2nd]
...
```

At present, the script only iterates through the counters, twice (i.e. N = 2 in this case). The goal is to be able to be able to iterate through these counters "many" (e.g. a couple hundred) times.

Currently the script reads the raw value of each counter into a single array. Here it is:

```
$cntr = (get-counter -listset tcpv4).paths
$arry = @()

for ($i=0; $i -lt 2; $i++) {
    write-host "`nThis is iteration $i`n"
    foreach ($elmt in $cntr) {
        $z = (get-counter -counter $elmt).countersamples[0].rawvalue
        $arry = $arry + $z
        write-host "$elmt is: $z`n"
    }
}
```

When I run this script, I get output just like the following:

```
This is iteration 0

\TCPv4\Segments/sec is: 24723

\TCPv4\Connections Established is: 27

\TCPv4\Connections Active is: 796

\TCPv4\Connections Passive is: 47

\TCPv4\Connection Failures is: 158

\TCPv4\Connections Reset is: 412

\TCPv4\Segments Received/sec is: 14902

\TCPv4\Segments Sent/sec is: 9822

\TCPv4\Segments Retransmitted/sec is: 199


This is iteration 1

\TCPv4\Segments/sec is: 24727

\TCPv4\Connections Established is: 27

\TCPv4\Connections Active is: 798

\TCPv4\Connections Passive is: 47

\TCPv4\Connection Failures is: 159

\TCPv4\Connections Reset is: 412

\TCPv4\Segments Received/sec is: 14903

\TCPv4\Segments Sent/sec is: 9824

\TCPv4\Segments Retransmitted/sec is: 200
```

e.g. The two values for the rawvalue property for the "\TCPv4\Segments Retransmitted/sec" counter are $arry[8] and $arry[17] respectively. To derive the difference between the two I'm using:

```
write-host "The difference between the successive counters for $($cntr[-1]) is $($($arry[17]) - $($arry[8]))."
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you want this data to be displayed? So for every value you want to know the difference of the previous? Basically doubling your output/

Comment: @Matt, thanks for the reply. How to display the data is TBD. Yes, presently I only want to know the difference between the current and the immediately preceding value of each counter.

Comment: Well here is hoping that I exceeded you expectations.

Answer (score 1):

I poked at it some, and this fell out:

```
$cntr = (get-counter -listset tcpv4).paths
$LastValue = @{}

Get-Counter $cntr -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 5 |
foreach {
  foreach ($Sample in $_.CounterSamples)
   {
     $ht = [Ordered]@{
        Counter   = $Sample.path.split('\')[-1]
        TimeStamp = $_.TimeStamp
        RawValue  = $Sample.RawValue
        LastValue = $LastValue[$Sample.Path]
        Change    = $Sample.RawValue - $LastValue[$Sample.Path]
        }
     if ($LastValue.ContainsKey($Sample.path))
       { [PSCustomObject]$ht }
     $LastValue[$Sample.Path] = $Sample.RawValue
   }
 }
```

Edit:

This should work on V2:

```
$cntr = (get-counter -listset tcpv4).paths
$LastValue = @{}

Get-Counter $cntr -SampleInterval 10 -MaxSamples 3 |
foreach {
  foreach ($Sample in $_.CounterSamples)
   {
     $Object = '' | 
      Select-Object Counter,TimeStamp,RawValue,LastValue,Change
      $Object.Counter   = $Sample.path.split('\')[-1]
      $Object.TimeStamp = $_.TimeStamp
      $Object.RawValue  = $Sample.RawValue
      $Object.LastValue = $LastValue[$Sample.Path]
      $Object.Change    = $Sample.RawValue - $LastValue[$Sample.Path]

     if ($LastValue.ContainsKey($Sample.path))
       { $Object }

     $LastValue[$Sample.Path] = $Sample.RawValue
   }
 }
```

Comment: The op tagged 2.0 so I dont think `[Ordered]` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Well lets work with this then

```powershell
$cntr = (get-counter -listset tcpv4).paths
$arry = @()
$maximumIterations = 2  # Variable based since you intended to change this. 

# Cycle the counters while recording the values. Once completed we will calculate change.
for ($i=1; $i -le $maximumIterations; $i++) {
    foreach ($elmt in $cntr) {
        $arry += New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject -Property @{
            Iteration = $i
            Counter = $elmt
            RawValue = (get-counter -counter $elmt).countersamples[0].rawvalue
            Change = $null
        }
    }
}

# Now that we have all the values lets calculate the rate of change over each iteration.
$arry | Where-Object{$_.Iteration -gt 1} | ForEach-Object{
    $previousIteration = $_.Iteration - 1 
    $thisCounter = $_.Counter
    $thisValue = $_.RawValue
    $previousValue = ($arry | Where-Object{$_.Counter -eq $thisCounter -and $_.Iteration -eq $previousIteration}).RawValue
    $_.Change = $thisValue - $previousValue
}

$arry | Select Iteration,Counter,RawValue,Change
```

Not that we *have* to but I collected all of the counters data along with their iteration value like you were putting against `Write-Host`. You will notice that I create a placeholder for `Change` but do not populate it. Before the calculations `$arry` would have data like the following. Note: the output is truncated

```powershell
Iteration Change Counter                           RawValue
--------- ------ -------                           --------
        1        \TCPv4\Segments/sec               28324837
        1        \TCPv4\Connections Established         120
        .        ..............................       .....
        2        \TCPv4\Segments/sec               28325441
        2        \TCPv4\Connections Established         125
```

Once all of that data is collected into `$arry` we get all the iterations that are not the first and process each item individually. Using the data of the current item in the pipeline we match it up with the previous iterations value. Using the same values as above we get the changes you were hoping to monitor

```powershell
Iteration Counter                           RawValue Change
--------- -------                           -------- ------
        1 \TCPv4\Segments/sec               28324837       
        1 \TCPv4\Connections Established         120 
        . ..............................       .....         
        2 \TCPv4\Segments/sec               28325441 604   
        2 \TCPv4\Connections Established         125 5
```

Comment: mjolinor, Matt: thanks to each of you for your answers. They both meet the requirements. Apologies for the delay in my reply.

Comment: @tre2015 I can sleep now. Hopefully we were able to help!

Comment: ha. Yes sir, you were both helpful. Been away from the site for months, so first order of business was to thank you guys. Thanks again.